# pushing ViewController and popping causes core data objects to lose values

Tags: core-data, ios5

I am pushing a View Conroller and then when I pop it via a segment controller to get back to the original. A couple of values will change. One is a distance value (a float) and the other is a thumbnail which is stored as a Binary Data.

Is there a way to tell Core Data to essentially freeze this array (it is currently an Array) before it pushes the other View Controller? Maybe copy it to a tmpArray and then copy back that tmpArray on viewDidAppear if it exists? Sounds really hacky but I need to get this to work.

thx

**edit #1**

So here is some code around where things go wrong. So it seems like the getAllLocationsWithFinished is causing the self.tmpLocations to change:

```
  //works
  NSLog(@"#1 locations right before call: %@",[self.locations objectAtIndex:2]);
  self.tmpLocations=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.locations copy]];
  //works
  NSLog(@"#2 locations right before call: %@",[self.tmpLocations objectAtIndex:2]);

  [[ModelManager sharedModelManager] getAllLocationsWithFinished:^(NSArray* map_locations) 
  {
    // data is off
    NSLog(@"#3 locations right before call: %@",[self.tmpLocations objectAtIndex:2]);
```

Comment: Are you sure the `getAllLocationsWithFinished` callback method is getting called on the main thread? Also how is your `tmpLocations` property declared? Strong? Try the following before the block runs and after you assign the property with your array of locations: `__block NSArray *testArray = self.tmpLocations;` then NSLog the `*testArray` inside the block.

Comment: tmpLocations is declard strong. getAllLocationsWithFinished willrun on a background thread. when I NSLog the testArray both distance and defaultImageData are nil. The other values are set correctly

Answer (score 0):

timpone,

If you are creating these items in the view controller, then you can guarantee they remain as they are by saving them. That said, I would be very surprised if Core Data is your culprit here. The navigation controller is an orthogonal technology to Core Data; they are independent of each other.

Are you absolutely sure that no memory warnings are occurring while the pushed view controller is visible? They frequently occur, particularly when BLOBs are involved, with navigation controllers. Your code may be responsible for the changing values.

If you are using GCD to perform back ground tasks in `-getAllLocationsWithFinished:`, then you are, most likely, not catching the did save notification from your background MOC. This must be caught and the objects merged between threads to keep your main thread's objects in sync with the background.

Andrew

Comment: not using GCD for background tasks. We aren't even saving the objects locally. I'd agree that I don't think it's a core data issue. For some reason, this Map Controller is causing problems - these are separate classes so they should not be able to manipulate values in the other. That's one of the reasons why I suspect Core Data since it's a common piece. I turned on SQL debugging but it didn't provide any information.

Comment: timpone, your problem is obviously within `-getAllLocationsWithFinished:`. That is where you need to perform some divide and conquer logging. Andrew

Comment: so, I agree it's changing within that block - that's the dilemna; is there any way I can wrap this in a notification to see who is changing this (as a debugging mechanism). Sorry - kinda new to debugging these iOS type problems.

Comment: I guess what gets me is that I'm copying it into a new tmpArray and still it gets changed. This should be totally separate in memory, right? The way I understand blocks is that the variable self.tmpLocations should go into scope and essentially stay that way. It's not clear at all why this value is changing at that point.

Comment: timpone, copying an array is not a deep copy. Hence, the objects in both arrays are the same. NSLog is your friend. Print things out and read the results. Divide the block in half and find out where the changes happen. Debugging iOS is not different than on other computers. Andrew